# Django ForeignKey is returning ID number instead of actual string value, particularly for form-based request.POST

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys

I have a website contact form that generates a dropdown box of "names" that are defined in another model "Data". The contact form runs off the model "Quote". As such, I use a ForeignKey reference to populate the "Data" information within the "Quote"-driven form.

However, the next step is to move this data to more python code (i.e., for calculations and placement in an email). But, when I request.POST "name" in the quote views file, I receive an ID (i.e., 1) instead of the actual string value for "name." I have read this is how ForeignKey inherently transfers data.

Like how I returned the actual string version of "name" in the quote dropdown box, how do I get the actual string version of "name" in a data request.POST / data_dictionary assignment? I have seen similar questions, but I am not completely sure of the simplest answer.

**models.py (Original one)**

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**models.py (The one tied to the form)**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

**views.py**

```
def quote_req(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        name = request.POST['name']
        if form.is_valid():
            data_dict = {
                'name_': str(name),
            inputdictionary = data_dict
```

**forms.py**

```
class QuoteForm(ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_show_labels = False
    required_css_class = 'required'
    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = ['name',]
```

**Variable Assignment**

```
 ▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
name        '1'
```

**Respective Error (I need the actual string value of "name")**

```
IndexError at /quote/

list index out of range
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your form is a `ModelForm` to create/modify a `Quote` instance, so after you instantiate and validate it, `form.cleaned_data['name']` will be the **actual `Data` instance** that was selected and `form.cleaned_data['name'].name` will be the `name` field of that instance.

Comment: @dirkgroten I want to retain the variable "name" by it's actual string value, not an ID, when I refer to it later in Python code that uses the model Data as the template for the master database.

Comment: But I just told you how to get `name` string from the submitted form.

Comment: @dirkgroten Apologies, but I am misunderstanding where I apply form.cleaned_data['name'] correctly in my code.

Comment: In your view, after if form.is_valid

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in tandem with what @dirkgroten mentioned in the comments. I have to add the form.cleaned_data method after the if form.is_valid statement. No other files need to be modified.

**views.py**

```
def quote_req(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        name = request.POST['name']
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            data_dict = {
                'name_': str(name),
            inputdictionary = data_dict
```